# Google Analytics Single Application Issue

Tags: google-analytics

I have setup google analytics on a small 1 page application website with 3 sections. I have implemented page fields and tracker object. However, every page title in google analytics is coming across as "Contact" although I have designated page titles for each pageview as below:

```
  ga('create', 'UA-50789730-1', 'auto');
    ga('set', {
        page: '/',
        title: 'Home'
    });
    ga('set', {
        page: '/#features',
        title: 'Features'
    });
    ga('set', {
        page: '/#download',
        title: 'Download'
    });
    ga('set', {
        page: '/#contact',
        title: 'Contact'
    });
    ga('send', 'pageview', '/');
    ga('send', 'pageview', '/#features');
    ga('send', 'pageview', '/#download');
    ga('send', 'pageview', '/#contact');
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you call `set` you're overriding the previously set data. That's why "Contact" is all you're seeing for the title in the code shown above, since that `set` call overrides the previous two.

I'd recommend reading the analytics.js overview to get a better idea of how the underlying library works:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

Then once you have a better understanding, you should read the guide on tracking single page applications, as there are some gotchas you should be aware of:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications